# Why is GL_LINES blurry?

Tags: opengl

Consider the following code:

```
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255,255);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2i(100, 100);
glVertex2i(300, 100);
glVertex2i(300, 101);
glVertex2i(100, 101);
glEnd();

glLineWidth(1);

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2i(100,200);
glVertex2i(300,200);
glEnd();
```

That results in the following, which I don't understand:

[image: GL_LINES v GL_QUADS]

I have not enabled (and actually have gone so far as to disable) GL_LINE_SMOOTH and GL_SMOOTH. If this is a global anti-aliasing "feature," shouldn't it affect GL_QUADS as well?

Halp?

Answer (score 5):

It is because you passed a coordinate which is halfway between two pixels.

For quads, borders between pixels are good and give you nice clean edges.

For lines, vertices between pixels causes half the line to fall on each.  For example, if you were using `glLineWidth(2)`, then this would work very well (half the line is exactly one pixel, so there's exactly one pixel to either side).  For `glLineWidth(1)`, you're getting only half a pixel to either side.

Comment: I thought so, but then why doesn't the GL_QUADS show the same result for the same coords? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: @Chris: But you don't give the same coords -- the quad goes from exactly y=100 to exactly y=101, centered on y=100.5  The line is centered on y=200.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Thank you!

Comment: (I meant when Y for the lower line is the same, but I see how the Quad is centered differently.)

Answer (score 1):

What if you do this?

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(100, 200.5f);
glVertex2f(300, 200.5f);
glEnd();
```